# Where are collected CPU counters visible in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, profiling

Once a project has been profiled in instrumentation mode and the various portable and platform events from the CPU counters menu have been selected where should they be visible?

In the profile report all the basic performance data is visible (cpu time, calls, etc...) however but not the selected CPU counters.

They are not present in the Marks section either.  There are only Windows counters, regardless of whether they were enabled or selected.

Comment: I'd say you're spot on Hans, I'm using windows 8, and the CPU counters probably got lost as well as the other features lisetd in the link.

Comment: Actually there it's just a matter of launching VS as admin - crazy that it prompts you when you run the memory profiler but not when you've selected CPU counters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CPU counters appear in the Functions view of the profiling report.  In order for them to be collected you must run Visual Studio as administrator.  There is a warning in the output window if you do not do this.